# Kann man Hilfe entstehen lassen?

Tags: word-usage

Ich habe gerade auf unserer Meta-Seite diesen Beitrag gefunden: [Hilfe, ich spreche kein Englisch! (work in progress)](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/979/hilfe-ich-spreche-kein-englisch-work-in-progress)

Der allererste Satz dieses Beitrags lautet:

> Hier entsteht die deutschsprachige Willkommensseite und Hilfe für unsere Seite (...).

gekürzt also:

> Hier entsteht Hilfe.

Das klingt so, als würde gerade irgendwo Hilfe produziert oder erzeugt, die dann abgepackt und versandfertig gemacht wird, so wie man das mit Eistee oder Brot macht.

Ich glaube nicht, dass man Hilfe, Beistand, Fürsorge, Unterstützung, Erlösung usw. herstellen, produzieren, machen, anfertigen oder entstehen lassen kann. Das spießt sich gewaltig mit meinem Sprachempfinden.

Ich glaube, dass man Hilfe *leisten* oder *angedeihen lassen* kann.

Wenn es aber, wie im zitierten Satz, darum geht etwas entstehen zu lassen, das jemandem später helfen soll, dann ist das hergestellte Werkstück keine Hilfe, sondern eine Hilfe-Seite oder eine Anleitung, und man müsste den zitierten Satz anders formulieren (was aber nicht Gegenstand dieser Frage sein soll).

Meine Frage lautet:

Ist es gutes und stilistisch hochwertiges Deutsch, zu sagen, dass man Hilfe entstehen lässt?

---

### Nachtrag

Aufgrund eines Kommentars:

Zunächst sollte der Numerus-Fehler im Prädikat korrigiert werden, weil hier ja zwei Dinge entstehen. Ich wollte nur eigentlich darauf nicht näher eingehen, weil das nicht Thema meiner Frage ist. Also:

> Hier <del>*entsteht*</del> **entstehen** *(zwei Dinge)*.

Der ursprüngliche Satz lässt offen, ob dort das Wort »Hilfe« mit oder ohne Artikel verwendet wird. Ich habe beim Lesen nur die Version ohne Artikel wahrgenommen, die in der folgenden Abwandlung auch die einzig mögliche ist:

> Hier entstehen **der** deutschsprachige Willkommens**bereich** und Hilfe für unsere Seite (...).

Eine andere Interpretationsmöglichkeit des Originalsatzes ist diese:

> Hier entstehen die deutschsprachige Willkommensseite und **die** Hilfe für unsere Seite (...).

Dann lautet die Kurzversion, die ich zur Diskussion stelle:

> Hier entsteht die Hilfe.

Die Frage lautet nun: Kann man eine Hilfe entstehen lassen?

Comment: Na ja, die Kürzung ist ein wenig unfair; eigentlich ist es _Hier entsteht **die** Hilfe_. Das ist sicher kein Kandidat für den Stilnobelpreis, aber geht.

Comment: @chirlu: Diese Interpretation des Satzes kam mir gar nicht in den Sinn. Jetzt erst erkenne ich nämlich, das die Konstruktion des ursprünglichen Satzes auch die Möglichkeit bietet, das Wort »die« auch als Artikel von »Hilfe« zu interpretieren. Würde man nämlich »*die deutschsprachige Willkommensseite*« durch »*der Willkommensbereich*« ersetzen, wäre es nicht mehr möglich, den vorhandenen Artikel zum Wort »Hilfe« dazuzudenken. (Aus diesem Grund habe ich bei ersten Lesen dieses Satzes auch keinen Artikel bei "Hilfe" wahrgenommen). Aber auch mit Artikel wird der Satz nicht wirklich besser.

Comment: Dessen ungeachtet müsste das Prädikat »entstehen« im Plural stehen, weil mehrere Dinge entstehen.

Comment: Das ist eine Haessliche Formulierung, die enstehen konnte weil immer mehr Menschen das Benutzerhandbuch erst Onlinehilfe und dann nur noch Hilfe zu nennen begonnen haben. Gemeint ist also die Hilfe als Onlinetext, nicht als Akt.

Comment: Steht Hilfe nicht einfach für Hilfeseite? Und einige Wörterbücher definieren "Hilfe" im IT-Kontext als Programm/Programmteil. Ja, das ist hier kein Programm, aber da kann man dann die Hilfe sehr wohl erzeugen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Hier entsteht Hilfe.

Klingt intuitiv total falsch – das würde nie jemand sagen.

> Hier entstehen Hilfeseiten.

würde gehen.

Answer (score 0):

Es kommt auch darauf an was man damit ausdrücken will, so wie es ganz oben steht erweckt es den Eindruck Willkommensseite und Hilfe wären eine Einheit.

Comment: Heißt das *ja* oder *nein*? Die Frage lautet nämlich: »Kann man (eine) Hilfe entstehen lassen?«

Comment: Wenn die Willkommensseite auch gleichzeitig die Hilfe zur Website ist müsste man eigentlich auf "Hier entsteht die Willkommensseite und Hilfe" kürzen, dann Ja. Jedenfalls wird Hilfe hier im IT-Kontext eher wie "Hilfe-Funktion/Seite" zu behandeln sein.

Answer (score 0):

**Ich finde, dass *Hilfe* eine gute Wortwahl ist.**

*Hilfe* wird oft bei Computerprogrammen gebraucht um die Hilfsseiten zu bezeichnen. Viele Dialoge haben neben einem *OK*- und *Abbrechen*- auch einen *Hilfe*-Knopf. Daher ist es, meiner Meinung nach, klar, dass *Hilfe* hier nicht zwischenmenschliche Hilfe sondern ein Dokument welches einem Benutzer helfen soll, bezeichnet.

Nimmt man es sehr genau ist es keine Hilfe sondern eine *Benutzeranleitung* oder *Dokumentation der Funktion dieser Seite*. Diese sind aber lange und relativ komplexe Begriffe. Da hier aber die Hemmschwelle möglichst gering gehalten werden soll und Leute, die neu sind nicht durch lange komplizierte Begriffe abgeschreckt werden sollen, ist Hilfe durchaus eine gute Wahl.

**Letztendlich sollte hier Einfachheit und Intuition stärker als grammatikalische Korrektheit gewichtet werden.**

Answer (score 0):

Hier regiert das blanke Elend.

Damit will ich sagen, dass die Sprache sehr formbar ist. Man sagt auch "Du warst keine große Hilfe" oder "Die Anleitung war keine große Hilfe" und eine Anleitung wird produziert und gemacht und vorgehalten für den Fall, dass sie gebraucht wird, und gerade nicht live in dem Moment geleistet, wenn sie vonnöten ist. Letzteres gibt es auch, und heißt hier Chat.

Die Hilfe fällt auch nicht fertig vom Himmel sondern entsteht.

Also ja, Hilfe wird gemacht wie Brot und Eistee. Erst plant man es, dann bereitet man es vor, dann macht man es und am Ende vermasselt man es doch.

> Wo aber Gefahr ist, wächst Das Rettende auch.
>   — Friedrich Hölderlin (1802)